# Placing values in a separate column based on multiple row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have the following table:

```
Index Product       Start   End   2012   2013   2014   2015   2016  2017   2018   
0     product a     2015    2017  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN    
1     product b     2008    2017  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN    
2     product c     2012    2015  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN    
3     product d     2033    2034  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN    
4     product e     2014    2020  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
```

And I want to convert it to this:

```
Index Product    Start End  2012      2013      2014      2015      2016      2017      2018    
0     product a  2015  2017 NaN       NaN       NaN       product a product a product a NaN     
1     product b  2008  2017 product b product b product b product b product b product b NaN     
2     product c  2012  2015 product c product c product c product c NaN       NaN       NaN     
3     product d  2033  2034 NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN     
4     product e  2014  2020 NaN       NaN       product e product e product e product e product e
```

So if the columns 2012-2018 exist between Start and End, then place the product in the appropriate cell based on the column name.

I know this is possible, but I'm struggling to find the solution. It's a combination of column name and not having a specific value, but a range, that is confusing me.

I'm using python dataframes.

The column names 2012-2018 represent the last two digits of the year concat with the week number. So March 18th, 2020 occurs in the 12th week of 2020, so it becomes 2012.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We can do `numpy` broadcast then assign it back

```
s=df.columns[3:].astype(int).values[:,None]
df.iloc[:,3:]=pd.DataFrame((df.Start.values<=s)&(s<=df.End.values)).T.mul(df.Product,0).values


df
Out[191]: 
        Product  Start   End      2012  ...      2015      2016      2017      2018
Index                                   ...                                        
0      producta   2015  2017            ...  producta  producta  producta          
1      productb   2008  2017  productb  ...  productb  productb  productb          
2      productc   2012  2015  productc  ...  productc                              
3      productd   2033  2034            ...                                        
4      producte   2014  2020            ...  producte  producte  producte  producte
[5 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Product','Start','End'], value_vars=[2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018])

df['value']=np.where((df['variable']>=Start) &(df['variable']<=end), 'Product', df['value'])

df=df.pivot_table(index=['Product','Start','End'], columns='variable', values='value')

df_df.reset_index()
```